# Data binding with jQuery not working with chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-binding

I was reading [this article](http://www.lucaongaro.eu/blog/2012/12/02/easy-two-way-data-binding-in-javascript/) and for some reason I cannot get this code to work in chrome- IE9 works without issue.

Here is the js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

function DataBinder( object_id ) {
    // Use a jQuery object as simple PubSub
    var pubSub = jQuery({});

    // We expect a `data` element specifying the binding
    // in the form: data-bind-<object_id>="<property_name>"
    var 
        data_attr = "bind-" + object_id,
        message = object_id + ":change";

    // Listen to change events on elements with the data-binding attribute and proxy
    // them to the PubSub, so that the change is "broadcasted" to all connected objects
    jQuery( document ).on( "change", "[data-" + data_attr + "]", function( evt ) {
        var $input = jQuery( this );
        console.dir('test message');

        pubSub.trigger( message, [ $input.data( data_attr ), $input.val() ] );
    });

    // PubSub propagates changes to all bound elements, setting value of
    // input tags or HTML content of other tags
    pubSub.on( message, function( evt, prop_name, new_val ) {
        jQuery( "[data-" + data_attr + "=" + prop_name + "]" ).each( function() {
            var $bound = jQuery( this );

            if ( $bound.is("input, textarea, select") ) {
                $bound.val( new_val );
            } else {
                $bound.html( new_val );
            }
        });
    });

    return pubSub;
};

function User( uid ) {
    var binder = new DataBinder( uid ),

            user = {
                attributes: {},

                // The attribute setter publish changes using the DataBinder PubSub
                set: function( attr_name, val ) {
                    this.attributes[ attr_name ] = val;
                    binder.trigger( uid + ":change", [ attr_name, val, this ] );
                },

                get: function( attr_name ) {
                    return this.attributes[ attr_name ];
                },

                _binder: binder
            };

    // Subscribe to the PubSub
    binder.on( uid + ":change", function( evt, attr_name, new_val, initiator ) {
        if ( initiator !== user ) {
            user.set( attr_name, new_val );
        }
    });

    return user;
};


var user = new User( 123 );
user.set( "name", "Wolfgang" );
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <script src="../../jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <input type="number" data-bind-123="name" />

    <script src="js/myjsfile.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

I added console.dir('test message') which should be logged when a change event gets fired on the input box. In IE i see this message, but in Chrome I do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I dumb, this was user error + IE weirdness. In my testing I was entering a string into the input box, but the input type is set to "number". It seems Chrome won't fire a change event if the type doesn't match, but IE will? Either way in IE I type whatever the heck in the box, the event fires and I see my "test message" in the console. In chrome I have to type a number and if I type a string nothing happens. Please let me know if I'm misinterpreting this behavior.